# Firefox doesn't work with new Date() with format like "Wed. October 28, 2015"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

this is what I have.

```
 date = testInfoSelect.testDate;
 console.log(date);
 date = new Date(date);
 console.log(date);
 date = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
 console.log(date);
```

This is the console output in FF.

```
"Wed. February 24, 2016"
Invalid Date
"NaN/NaN/NaN"
```

This is the console output in Chrome.

```
Wed. February 24, 2016
Wed Feb 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
02/24/2016
```

For my application, I can NOT change the date format, which is testInfoSelect.testDate, in this case is "Wed. February 24, 2016".

What I did:

> dateString String value representing a date. The string should be in a
>   format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

The most similar date formate in MDN documentation is this:

```
Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
```

What should I do to get the correct result in FF without changing the format of "Wed. February 24, 2016"

Thanks

Comment: It's a hack, but you can do `date = date.replace(".", "")` and it will work, the period messes it up

Comment: not to force you to use a library, but have you considered moment.js? It's super helpful for date manipulation – 11.5k gz'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack, as mentioned by @adeno, you could:

```
new Date("Wed. February 24, 2016".replace('.', ''));
```

or

```
new Date("Wed. February 24, 2016".replace('.', ','));
```

in your case:

```
new Date(date.replace('.', ''));
```

To get GMT time you could do something like:

```
> new Date(date.replace('.', '') + " GMT");
< Date 2016-02-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

Results for FF, Chrome and Opera:

Firefox:

```
▶ new Date("Wed. February 24, 2016".replace('.', '') + " GMT");
⯇ Date 2016-02-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

Chrome:

```
 > new Date("Wed. February 24, 2016".replace('.', '') + " GMT");
<- Wed Feb 24 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Opera:

```
>>> new Date("Wed. February 24, 2016".replace('.', '') + " GMT");
[+] Wed Feb 24 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```